# Plesk: Access ouside public folder

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

I’m working on a web site that is hosted on a shared server that uses Plesk.

I want to put the database users config files outside of the public folder (httpdocs) and access them with include_once.
The problem is that the pages that use “include_once” don’t open in a browser, giving an error 500. Looking at the error log I found that the problem is caused by permission issues:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PATH TO DB CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in PATH TO/httpdocs/index.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PATH TO DB CONFIG' (include_path='.:') in PATH TO/httpdocs/index.php on line 2
```

The folders have a permission of 755, but I think the problem is happening because Plesk doesn’t allow access to folders outside the public folder.

Is there any way to allow access to those files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set open_basedir for the user, you can do this in Plesk under hosting settings, or via Apache config directly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on a shared hosting, and I can't modify the PHP settings and Apache config.

Comment: Can you not modify the php settings on a per site basis? This has been possible in Plesk for some time now. I run many VPS running Plesk and need to do this exact thing myself now and again, on a per site basis.